# java| how to create block same-length String

Tags: java, arrays, search, block, string-length

I want to built in ten arrays of size n and place in the first stings of length one, in the second strings of length two and so forth where the tenth array has strings of length ten.

```
Array String = { a, b, the , c , no, yes, and, or, ...}

Array length_string = [ 1 , 1, 3,   1 , 2, 3,  3 , 2 , ....}
```

I don't understand how to do this, place string with same length into block:

```
 [a,b,c]  //every string length =1 
 
 [no,or]   // every string length =2

 [the,yes,and]  // every string length =3
```

and so on

Edit:

I found hash Map work with my code

`` `final Map<Integer, List> lengthToWords = new TreeMap<>(
Arrays.stream(words).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length))); ``

But how can control block size
I meaning want each block = 256

1 [ a , b ,c ,...] number element =256 , not more that

2 [ aa, bb, cc ,..] number element =256

and so on until ten block
I have ten block by using loop , Now i need limit number element inside block

Comment: What is the max length of a String? Or do you provide it?

Comment: mainArray i give size each test ( maybe which is 500 or a thousand or so, it's file text), but the ten array (blocks) is a fixed size 256, condition in block it's same length string .

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your solution doesn't need to be efficient or your array size is limit you can do it with nested loops.

```
for(int i =1;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<stringArray.length;j++){
        if(i == stringArray[j].length){
               resultArray[i-1] = stringArray[j];
               break;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

Be careful to check arrayIndexOutOfBound exception

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arr= { "a", "b", "the" , "c" , "no", "yes", "and", "or"};
     String length1="[";
     String length2="[";
     String length3 ="[";
    
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
     {
        switch(arr[i].length())
       {
       case 1:
    length1=length1+ arr[i]+",";
    break;
    case 2:
    length2=length2+ arr[i]+",";
    break;
    case 3:
    length3=length3+ arr[i]+",";
    break;
    
       }
    
    }
    
    if (length1.endsWith(",")) {
        length1 = length1.substring(0, length1.length()-1);
    }
    if (length2.endsWith(",")) {
        length2 = length2.substring(0, length2.length()-1);
    }
    if (length3.endsWith(",")) {
        length3 = length3.substring(0, length3.length()-1);
    }
    
    length1=length1+"]";
       length2=length2+"]";
       length3=length3+"]";
    
       System.out.println(length1);
       System.out.println(length2);
    
       System.out.println(length3);
```

output :

```
[a,b,c]
[no,or]
[the,yes,and]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete Java code with example input. The createBlockList does the following: 1) Create a list of lists to store the result. 2)Iterate through the string array and place the string in the right lists.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
  public static void createBlockList(String[] strArr, int[] strLenArr) {
     List<List<String>>resList = new ArrayList<>();
     for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
         resList.add(new ArrayList());
     }
     for(int i=0; i<strArr.length; i++) {
         int strLen = strLenArr[i];
         resList.get(strLen-1).add(strArr[i]);
     }
 }
 public static void main(String []args){
    String str[] = {"a","b","in","on","the","and"};
    int len[] = {1,1,2,2,3,3};
    createBlockList(str, len);
 }
```

}